# Aligning objects in custom LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, custom-view

I have custom coded layout to hold all the childs. Here is the code:

```
public abstract class ItemView extends LinearLayout{
    private ImageView icon;//cell icon
    public static final int iconID=12345;
    private Button accessorButton;//this will not be button ?
    public static final int accessorID=54321;



    public ItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public  void arrange(){

    }
    public  void setView(Context context){  
        int l=super.getLeft();
        int r=super.getRight();
        int t=super.getTop();
        int b=super.getBottom();
        icon=new ImageView(context);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        addView(icon);
        accessorButton=new Button(context);
        accessorButton.setText("accessor");
        addView(accessorButton);
       // icon.layout(l+5, t+5, l+100, b-5);
        //accessorButton.layout(r-100, t+5, r-10, b-5);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);


    }


}
```

and I have child layouts, one of them is:

```
public class ItemPlainView extends ItemView{

    private TextView text;

    public ItemPlainView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setView(context);
    }
    public void setView(Context context){
      super.setView(context);
       text=new TextView(context);
       text.setText("plain view text");
       addView(text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);


    }
    public TextView getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(TextView text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void arrange() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

When I run the code it naturally gives me a star icon, a button and after that a TextView. I need to replace and resize my objects. For this example I need to put star icon at the most left TextView in the middle and my button on the most right side. Considering this hierarchical view, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you don't have the layout in a XML file? There's nothing that you are doing that you can't do in XML right now.

Comment: I create my layout and inner views on choice, there are plenty of them and I need to set everything in runtime. Also I got to set those layouts in a hierarchical manner. I thought it would bring me much comfort coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dymmeh is exactly right, every thing you are doing could be in your main.xml as follows:

@Steve i added another `TextView` as suggested, you would want to choose either the `TextView` before the `OR` or the `TextView` & `ImageView` after the `OR`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="plain view text"
        android:weight="1"
        />

    <<--OR-->>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star"
        android:weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="plain view text"
        android:weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="accessor"
        android:weight="1"
        />     
</LinearLayout>
```

then your java class would just have to call `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in your `onCreate` after `super.onCreate();`

much much easier than what you had. you can easily arrange any of those items any way you want also. see [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) you could also use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) but i think those are too complicated for most situations.

Comment: sorry i didnt see your comment, you can still do all starting with the xml and it will make things much easier, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: my linear layout will be a container for a row, and what it contains will be determined completely at runtime. I don't see any goodness of xml for that. I can't explain exactly what I need but I can tell you that I need to write it in code, thanks

Comment: well i will take your word for it, wish i could help more, one last thing though, if the only thing changing at runtime is the content but not the format or layout, this would still save you the trouble of doing all this programatically, as is done in the developer tutorials [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) for the format of each list item.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier using the XML layouts. I would suggest just using that. However, if you really need to do it in code, you can set the middle TextView to have a layout parameter with a layout_weight = 1.